# How to retrieve Users with a specific role via Linq in ASPnet Identity

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need to retrieve all users of a specific role, something I think should be made straightforward, however, here is the problem.

The Roles navigation Property of ApplicationUser is not the list of roles (IdentityRole) but a collection of (IdentityUserroles) the intermediate table that links users and roles. So, this is the code I have, but it does not work.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Recepcionista, Orientador")]
public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchCriteriaViewModel criteria)
{


    List<SearchResultViewModel> results = new List<SearchResultViewModel>();
    var clients = new List<ApplicationUser>();

    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        IdentityUserRole role = new IdentityUserRole();
        var tempRole = (from _role in context.Roles
                        where _role.Name == "client"
                        select _role).FirstOrDefault();
        role.Role = tempRole;

        clients = (from client in context.Users
                   where client.Email.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   || client.FirstName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   || client.MiddleName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   || client.LastName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   || client.SecondLastName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   || client.UserName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
                   && client.Roles.Contains(role)
                   select client).ToList();


    }

    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        results.Add(new SearchResultViewModel()
        {
            Email = client.Email,
            FirstName = client.FirstName,
            MiddleName = client.MiddleName,
            LastName = client.LastName,
            SecondLastName = client.SecondLastName,
            UserName = client.UserName
        });
    }

    SearchClientViewModel model = new SearchClientViewModel();
    model.SearchResults = results;

    return View("Index", model);

}
```

Linq throws the following Exception

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

How can this be done, Why the navigation properties is not a collection of Roles, could this be a bug we need to report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message is quite clear: you can't call `Contains` on collection of non-primitive objects.

Try following:

```
    clients = (from client in context.Users
               where client.Email.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               || client.FirstName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               || client.MiddleName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               || client.LastName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               || client.SecondLastName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               || client.UserName.Contains(criteria.SearchCriteria)
               && client.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).Contains("client")
               select client).ToList();
```

Comment: Anyway, Is it correct that the navigation property does not lead us to the user roles collection?

Comment: You can try using Include method to load navigation property eagerly.

Comment: But that navigation property of IdentityUserRoles instead of IdentityRoles. That´s what confused me

Comment: a PERFECT solution when we want to use contains!! thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure there is an API in Identity Framework to do so. But for your exception, please try :

```
&& client.Roles.Count(r => r.Name == "client") > 0
```

Comment: Or even :

    && client.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "client")