# How to filter ICollection<ApplicationUser> on a Role in ASP.NET MVC 5's Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have added 3 roles:

1. Administrators
2. Staff
3. Registered

Now I want to display a list of all `Registered` users. 
I'm afraid I'm not getting the Identity system, because I am trying to do something like this:

**Spoiler Alert: not working code**

```
var listOfNames = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.All()
                                            .Where(u => u.Roles.Contains("Registered"))
                                            .ToList();
```

This obviously does not work, so I went searching for an answer. Unfortunately I did not get any. The closest I could find was a post by Scott Allen who mentioned `IUserRoleStore` which has the following implementations:

- Add a user to a role
- Get all the roles for a user
- Check is a user is in a specific role
- Remove a user from a role

But still, not getting it :/

I have also tried the methods in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265031/how-to-retrieve-users-with-a-specific-role-via-linq-in-aspnet-identity), but `Roles.Select(r => r.Name).Contains("client")` does not work because the Name property can't be found?

How can I get this list of ApplicationUser objects?

### Update

---

Sean's answer helped me to dig a little deeper. I'm not sure this is the best way, but it works for my needs.

```
var users = context.Users;
var roleUsers = context.Roles.Single(one => one.Name == "Registered").Users;

names = (from r in roleUsers
join u in users on r.UserId equals u.Id
select u.UserName).ToList();
```

If this is inefficient, I'd love to hear why and how I can improve it.

Comment: Have you tried `Roles.GetUsersInRole("Registered")`?

Comment: @rcjames The Roles class is from the old (deprecated) Membership system and is unrelated to the newer ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming AspNetIdentity2.0...I see you are using a repository pattern  so in there, could you use the `RoleManager`:

```
var users = RoleManager.Roles.Single(x => x.Name == "Registered").Users;
```

Unfortunately (and misleadingly) this returns a list of `UserRoles` but at least you've got the users' `UserId`s, and from there, can fetch the `Users`.

Comment: hi how to filter table records by clientId/tenantId - this did not work in identity 2.2 ASP MVC 5 `var users = RoleManager.Roles.Single(x => x.Name == "Registered").Users;`